# Simple question about asymptotic notation

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I'm quiet new to the asymptotic world, so apology in advance if this question seems too trivial for you experts.

> Given $\frac{2kn2^{-k}}{E[X]}.$ As $k \sim 2\text{log}_{2} n$, the numerator is $n^{-1+o(1)}.$

I don't understand how the numerator comes out to be $n^{-1+o(1)}.$ Using $k \sim 2\text{log}_{2} n$,

$2kn2^{-k} = \frac{2kn}{2^{k}} \sim \frac{4n\text{log}_{2}n}{n^{2}} = \frac{4\text{log}_{2} n}{n}$.

For the last term to be $n^{{-1}+o(1)}$, $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exists $M$ such that for $n>M$, $\frac{4\text{log}_{2} n}{n} < n^{{-1}+\epsilon}=\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{n} \implies 4\text{log}_{2} n<n^{\epsilon}$.

As $n \rightarrow \infty, 4\text{log}_{2} n \rightarrow \infty $ but $n^{\epsilon} \rightarrow 1$, so how could there exist such $M$?

Thanks you!

Comment: If you believe that $4\log_2n=n^2$, you have some serious revisions to do.

Comment: @Did darn. I was so desperate to find the solution  that  i was seeing $4^{log_{2}n}$ instead