# Limit of $n^{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi(n) \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: limits

Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{\phi(n)}=1$  if $\phi(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: No.  Let, e.g., $\phi(n)=\frac {1}{log(n)}$.

Comment: @lulu thanks! the reason i asked this is because I'm confused by the interpretation of $f(n) =n^{o(1)}$. Always thought it meant $f(n) < 1, n>M$, for some constant M. Now it's clear I'm wrong, would you mind explaining(or redirect me) the meaning of $f(n) =n^{o(1)}$. Thanks again! ( i hope I'm not being annoying asking u question like this)

Comment: No problem.  Little o(1) just means the function goes to $0$, so your $\phi$ is $o(1)$.  I would expect the context to clarify things, but I would have expected $f(n)=n^{o(1)}$ to mean that $g(n)=\frac {f(n)}{log(n)}$ was $o(1)$. Is that consistent with whatever reference you are using?

Comment: @zfb, do you understand what $o(1)$ means?  This really seems like a new question (or a very significant edit to your original question).

Comment: @zfb to clarify:  your definition is neither big-O nor little-O.  $O(1)$ just means the function is bounded above.  $o(1)$ means the function actually tends to $0$.

Comment: @zfb Correction:  In an earlier comment, I ought to have written "I would have expected $f(n)=n^{o(1)}$ to mean that $g(n)=\frac {log(f(n))}{log(n)}$ was $o(1)$".

Comment: @lulu hmm i would get back to you in a few minutes when I'm in front of a computer. It's very hard to type using  this phone!

Comment: No problem.  Note my correction though...I carelessly omitted a "log" in what I typed before.

Comment: @TravisJ i use the definition from here http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/littleOnotation.html I get very confused when the o notation is used as exponent though

Comment: @zfb.  That definition is fine, though I would not have restricted it to positive functions $f(n)$.   In the case of $o(1)$, and positive functions $f(n)$, it means that, for all $c>0$ we may deduce the existence of a constant $k = k(c)$ such that $n>k\;\Rightarrow 0≤f(n)<c$.

Comment: @lulu is it correct then that $f(n) = g(n)^{o(1)}$ implies for all $c>0$, there exist constant k such that $n>k \implies 0 \leq f(n) < g(n)^{c}$ ? To give you a context here's the the question im referring to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403917/simple-question-about-asymptotic-notation Notice that i made a mistake at the end saying that $n^{\epsilon} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since I mistakenly thought that as $n \rightarrow \infty \implies \epsilon \rightarrow 0 \implies n^{\epsilon} \rightarrow 1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27204/discussion-between-lulu-and-zfb).

Comment: @lulu ok gimme about 30 mins if that's fine with you. I'm actually in the gym locker room typing on my phone :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Take $\phi(n)=\frac{1}{\ln(n)}=\log_n(e)$ which implies $n^{\phi(n)}=e$.